# Portable VSCode with Git - relative Git path

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup a portable version of VSCode with Git. I put portable git in the VSCode executable folder, under .\tools\Git.

I edited the settings file with the following:

```
{
    "git.path": "C:\\my-folder\\tools\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"
}
```

And this way it works well.

But if I change to the following, git doesn't work anymore:

```
{
    "git.path": ".\\tools\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"
}
```

From what I researched it seems that VSCode doesn't support relative paths in the settings file.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I use is:

- to *not* set the `PATH` in VSCode settings.
- to launch VSCode through a script which will first set `%PATH%` with the folders I need for VSCode to work, including `C:\my-folder\tools\Git\bin`

That script (which can be in `C:\my-folder\tools`) can:

- find its own path (where it currently resides),
- use that path as a basis for other paths relative to itself.

It can start with:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in ("%~dp0.") do SET "script_dir=%%~fi"
cd /d "%script_dir%" || echo "unable to cd to '%script_dir%'"&& exit /b 1

set PATH=%PATH%;%script_dir%\Git\bin
%script_dir%\VSCode\bin\code.cmd
```